# Sum of values in a dictionary - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

So this is just some similar example code below. I am trying to take the heights of all people and add them together so that I can get an average. I can't seem to figure out how to do this with an array of dictionaries. Also I am using Xcode 3.

```
let people = [
    [
    "name": "John Doe",
    "sex": "Male",
    "height": "183.0"
    ],
    [
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "sex": "Female",
    "height": "162.0"
    ],
    [
    "name": "Joe Doe",
    "sex": "Male",
    "height": "179.0"
    ],
    [
    "name": "Jill Doe",
    "sex": "Female",
    "height": "167.0"
    ],
]
```

The below code seems to just create new empty arrays.

```
var zero = 0.0
var peopleHeights = Double(player["height"]!)
var totalHeights = zero += peopleHeights!
```

The below code doubles each individual value so not what I am looking for.

```
var zero = 0.0
var peopleHeights = Double(player["height"]!)
var totalHeights = peopleHeights.map {$0 + $0}
```

In the below code I get the response: Value of type Double has no member reduce.

```
var peopleHeights = Double(player["height"]!)
var totalHeights = peopleHeights.reduce(0.0,combine: +)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `player` is an array, what do you expect `player["height"]` to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also simply iterate over your array of dictionaries.

```
var totalHeight: Double = Double()

for person in people
{
    totalHeight += Double(person["height"]!)!
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to extract height of each person using `map`. Then you can apply `reduce` on the list containing the heights:

*You should use `flatMap` (`compactMap` on Swift 4+) over `map` as `+` works only on unwrapped values.*

```
people.flatMap({ Double($0["height"]!) }).reduce(0, +)
```

**Swift 5**

```
people.compactMap { Double($0["height"]!) }.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: You don't want the `combine:` in Swift 3.  Also, you might want to consider using `?? ""` instead of `!` to safely unwrap the height string

Comment: how to use this in swift 5

Answer (score 2):

`compactMap` is good to use for the sum of values as it considers only non-nil values.

```
let totalHeights = people.compactMap { $0["height"] as? Double}.reduce(0, +)
```